# Re-categorize the parent array based on the child array's objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

(Also open to a php solution)

If I have an array within an array, how do you re-categorize the parent array based on the child array's objects?

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

Say if the original array is:

```
[
 {
  "name":"Jade",
  "tags":[
   "developer"
  ]
 },
 {
  "name":"Bridge",
  "tags":[
   "cook"
  ]
 },
 {
  "name":"Ever",
  "tags":[
   "artist"
  ]
 },
 {
  "name":"Noah",
  "tags":[
   "artist",
   "developer"
  ]
 }
]
```

I want to be able to re-categorize it into:

```
[
 "artist": {
    {
     {
      "name":"Noah",
      "tags":[
       "artist",
       "developer"
      ]
    }
  }
 "developer": {
   {
      "name":"Jade",
      "tags":[
       "developer"
      ]
      },
     {
      "name":"Noah",
      "tags":[
       "artist",
       "developer"
      ]
    }
  },
  "cook": {
    {
      "name":"Bridge",
      "tags":[
       "cook"
      ]
    },
  }
]
```

Here is what I tried:

(the original array is var data)

```
var data = [original array]
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (var a = 0; a < data[i].tags.length; a++) {
    newArray[] = data[i].tags[a];
    if (newArray[i] == data[i].tags[a]) {
      newArray[i] = data[i];
    }
  }
}
```

My theory is to pop the tag (in tags) into a new array, and if the original object.tags has same value as the new object in the array, pop the original object into the new object.

This approach failed.

Comment: well your code looks like javascript. And up there you have an array of Objects. So you will need to use object methods.

Comment: @floor Hey sorry. I was looking to do it through the front end, but if it is easier to do it through php, I can set up a back end to interpret this API. Thanks.

Comment: Your example for the expected result is broken and also a little strange. Surely you would want each job to contain an array of objects? (people)?

Comment: @rjdown Correct. I've noticed my solution is neither clean nor efficient. I am open to a smarter approach all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend a backend solution (php) as it will be significantly faster as you scale up.

```
<?php
    $sInFile  = 'in.json';
    $sOutFile = 'out.json';

    $aDevelopers = array();
    $aArtists    = array();
    $aCooks      = array();

    $sRaw       = file_get_contents( $sInFile );
    $aInData    = json_decode( $sRaw );
    $iCountData = count( $aInData );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountData; ++$i )
    {
        $iCountTags = count( $aInData[ $i ]->tags );
        for( $j = 0; $j < $iCountTags; ++$j )
        {
            $aTmp = array();
            if( ( !empty( $aInData[ $i ]->tags[ $j ] ) ) && $aInData[ $i ]->tags[ $j ] == 'developer' )
            {
                $aTmp[ 'name' ] = $aInData[ $i ]->name;
                $aTmp[ 'tags' ] = $aInData[ $i ]->tags;
                $aDevelopers[] = $aTmp;
            }
            $aTmp = array();
            if( ( !empty( $aInData[ $i ]->tags[ $j ] ) ) && $aInData[ $i ]->tags[ $j ] == 'artist' )
            {
                $aTmp[ 'name' ] = $aInData[ $i ]->name;
                $aTmp[ 'tags' ] = $aInData[ $i ]->tags;
                $aArtists[] = $aTmp;
            }
            $aTmp = array();
            if( ( !empty( $aInData[ $i ]->tags[ $j ] ) ) && $aInData[ $i ]->tags[ $j ] == 'cook' )
            {
                $aTmp[ 'name' ] = $aInData[ $i ]->name;
                $aTmp[ 'tags' ] = $aInData[ $i ]->tags;
                $aCooks[] = $aTmp;
            }
        }
    }

    $aFull[ 'developer'] = $aDevelopers;
    $aFull[ 'artist' ] = $aArtists;
    $aFull[ 'cook' ] = $aCooks;
    $sFull = json_encode( $aFull );
    file_put_contents( $sOutFile, $sFull );
?>
```

Comment: It looks like I will need to manually create new array categories as the number of tags goes up. Realistically there are about hundreds of these tags, and I think manually creating all of them will become unmanageable.

Comment: Converting to a dynamic profession detection array? :) You can tweak the script to do an array unique as it's building up temp placeholders and store them before committing the data to a profession.